# How to find the limit of $\frac{\frac{1 - 2n}{n}}{5 + 3^{-n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have an intuition that the limit is $\frac{-2}{5}$, by noting that $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ and $3^{-n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. But I do not know how to show this formally, i.e. we can always find a starting index $n$ such that $\left| \frac{2}{5} - \frac{\frac{1 - 2n}{n}}{5 + 3^{-n}} \right| < \epsilon$ for a given epsilon. By manipulating the absolute value I managed to get it to form $\left| \frac{-2n3^{-n} - 5}{5n3^{-n} + 25n}\right|$. I suppose the squeeze theorem is one way to go, but as of now I do not know what my two other sequences should be.

Comment: You want a plus sign separating the two terms the first time you write the absolute value, either that or write $-2/5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you allowed to use arithmetical operations with limits? You can use that $\frac{1 - 2n}{n} \to-2$ and $5 + 3^{-n} \to 5$ separately and then divide limits.

If no, then
$$\left|\frac{\frac{1 - 2n}{n}}{5 + 3^{-n}}+\frac{2}{5}\right|=\left|\frac{5+2n3^{-n}}{5n(5 + 3^{-n})}\right|< \frac{6}{5n}$$

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the operations with limits! To be honest I was looking for an approximation trick, like the one you pulled off. I suppose the eye for these kinds of things only come after enough exposure?

Comment: Quite possible.